# Вывод Dataframe в график matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Пытаюсь вывести кластеризацию Kmeans на графике. В данных 35 колонок. Совершенно не понимаю как получить вменяемые X и Y относительно центроида для вывода.

```
ds = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(ds)

Kmean=KMeans(n_clusters=4)
label = Kmean.fit_predict(df)



filt_lab0 = df[label == 0]
filt_lab1 = df[label == 1]
filt_lab2 = df[label == 2]
filt_lab3 = df[label == 3]

plt.scatter(filt_lab0.iloc[:,0], filt_lab0.iloc[:,1], color='r')
plt.scatter(Kmean.cluster_centers_[:,0] , Kmean.cluster_centers_[:,1] , color = 'y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы пытаетесь нарисовать на графике... Вы используете первые две размерности из 35-ти для того, чтобы визуализировать точки из 35-мерного пространства на двумерной плоскости?? Так это не работает. Если вам необходима визуализация - придется прибегнуть к техникам "dimensionality reduction"

Comment: Да, что за данные вообще, сколькимерные они? Мы же вообще ничего про данные не знаем.

Comment: Хочу визуализировать полученные кластеры в виде множества точек. Это уже что-то, спасибо